# Mocking Kafka producer/consumer in spring boot integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-kafka

I have to test one API, which internally calls Kafka producer and has Kafka consumer as well. I have a working spring boot test, which is actually sending and receiving messages over a Kafka host.

But now I don't want to actually use Kafka in the integration test as I was facing lag with Kafka messages, i want to mock the part where Kafka producer/consumer work is done.

Is there any way I can mock those things in a **spring boot test** and also I **don't have to build the Kafka messages objects either in my test**, someway i can extract the Kafka messages from the running integration test...

Answer (score 1):

Do not mock anything. Use embedded kafka.

See https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka

Embedded kafka is a "fake", not a "mock", of Kafka.

For a discussion of the differences between fakes and mocks, see https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html

Comment: And since you asked with `spring-kafka` tag, here is some solution from there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-annotation. However since you talk about mocks, here is an API from Apache Kafka Client by itself: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-mockproducer

Comment: Tried this approach with EmbeddedKafka, but it doesn't seem to work when the tests are run in parallel. Single tests are working, but in parallel they don't seem to work. Is it possible to run tests parallelly with EmbeddedKafka?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. You could look at their documentation and discussions on the github link I gave above, in case someone has encountered this issue before; if not, you could ask them about it. Be sure to post your findings here.